# Show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin {nx}}{a^n} = \frac{a \sin{x}}{1 + a^{2} - 2a \cos{x}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Show that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin {nx}}{a^n} = \frac{a \sin{x}}{1 + a^{2} - 2a \cos{x}}$$

I've been trying to use the geometric series rule for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{-n} = \frac{x}{x -1}$ as well as Euler for the $\sin(nx)$, but I just can't seem to get the series to reduce to the fraction on the right.  Could you help?

Comment: Please, include the problem in the body of the question too.

Answer (score 17):

Look at the imaginary part of $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\exp(inx)}{a^n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\dfrac{\exp(ix)}{a} \right)^n = \dfrac{a}{a-\exp(ix)}$$

Comment: hehe, nice (+1)

Comment: Thanks Marvis, that was super helpful!  That's a really clever maneuver taking the n out of the whole phrase.